# Is it possible to have ng-repeat append data to existing content instead of replacing?

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I have the following html:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items></li>
```

Everytime the user scrolls to the bottom of the list I'm loading 10 more items and I want to **append** them to the bottom of the list instead of just replacing the content that was there before.

Is there any way to do this with AngularJS?

Comment: put your controller code please

Comment: push those new 10 items to the `items` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was to use the native javascript concat() function, which merges two arrays. I merged the items already in my scope variable with the new ones the ajax request returned which had the desired effect of appending data, instead of replacing it.

So my ajax request looked something like this:

```
ajaxCallFetchItems().then(function(items) {
  $scope.items = $scope.items.concat(items);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use splice() function of javascript as:

```
var firstArr= ["One", "Two", "Tree", "Four"];
var secondArr= ["Five","Six"];
firstArr.splice(firstArr.length+1 , 0, secondArr);
```

result:

```
One,Two,Tree,Four,Five,Six
```

[See More Info on splice()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this would be what you search

```
function ItemsController($scope,Items){

  $scope.onScroll = function(amount){
    Items.getMore(amount).then(function(response){
      $scope.items.splice($scope.items.length+1 , 0, response.data);
    });
  }
}
```